# Page With Mixed Content?

Tags: php, ssl

Is there a way to check and prevent a form from being displayed if the page loads with mixed content?  thus meaning the page isnt using the ssl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to hide form if visitor opened page via non-ssl url. You could check prefix whether it is ssl or not. If it is not a SSL page you don't echo the form. Is that not work?

Below script will redirect visitor to ssl page if he/she is not on ssl page. Put this to top of page:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on") {
    $url = "https://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
```

You may use this script's other variations

Comment: i dont think with would work.  What if for some reason the page needs to load with mixed content.  If the mixed content is loaded is the page now not secured?

Comment: If you are talking about javascripts or images from non-ssl urls, browser may warn you about both secure and non-secure content. But indeed your forms inside your scripts will still be secure. Just be careful about linking to external javascripts where do you include them.

Comment: ie example: If im warned about the mixed content and wish to view the non secure items the lock doesnt appear.  Doesnt this mean the page is no longer secure?

Comment: If we are talking about forms inside page, they are still secure to send over that page. But if you are linking to external non-ssl javascripts -may be an ad connection- we cannot say page is totally secure. Because non-secure javascript connections are able to grab data from your page. So just be careful about external javascripts. If you don't use external javascripts check your background images url on css file. Change the url's into "https:// www. example.com/images/bg.png" (without gaps of course); type. You will no longer warned about mixed content.